# I get one more button after foreach loop by ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to add my edit button in every row of table with specificed value I get from my server side, but although I have n loop, it always display n + 1 button.

Here is my code:

script.js

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // function that use to load data from DB
                function loadData() {
                    $.post('../../loadData', function (dataResponse) {
                        var buttonEdit = $('<button type="button" id="editDoc" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#form-editDoc"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen text-dark"></i></button>');
                        var buttonDelete = $('<button type="button" class="deleteDoc" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can text-danger"></i></button>');
                        $.each(dataResponse[0], function (index, value) {
                            $('<tr>').appendTo($('#tableDoctor > tbody'))
                                    .append($('<th scope="row">').text(index + 1))
                                    .append($('<td>').text(value.name))
                                    .append($('<td>').text(value.mail))
                                    .append($('<td class="action">'));
                                    buttonEdit.appendTo($('td.action'));
                        })
                    });
                }
                loadData();
            })

        </script>
```

my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tableDoctor">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Mail</th>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn7Oo.png)

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Don't you need a `buttonDelete.appendTo($('td.action'));` in addition to the `buttonEdit.appendTo($('td.action'));` ?

Comment: Sorry I have a mistake at edit and delete, I mean edit button not delete, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues.

First, the line `buttonEdit.appendTo($('td.action'));` will append to *all* matches of `td.action` - for which there is one in *every* row of the table. So your first row would have as many Edit buttons as there are rows in the table. You need to scope this lookup to the current row.

However, you aren't seeing that many buttons because of the second issue. You have a single reference to the `buttonEdit` DOM element. When you append it to the next row, jQuery is removing its previous position. You need to [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element before you append it.

The code becomes:

```
$.each(dataResponse[0], function(index, value) {
  const row = $('<tr>')
    .append($('<th scope="row">').text(index + 1))
    .append($('<td>').text(value.name))
    .append($('<td>').text(value.mail))
    .append($('<td class="action">'));

  row.find('td.action')
    .append(buttonEdit.clone())
    .append(buttonDelete.clone());

  $('#tableDoctor > tbody').append(row);
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/b32xowrh/) is an example fiddle.